# Custom Class vs. Dictionary vs. struct

Tags: objective-c, performance

My program should save, retrieve and manipulate a large load of data. (Around 200,000 entries, which all have around 20 entries.)

I'm wondering how I should implement the data: create my own class, use a struct or use NSDictionary.

The whole data would be saved in an array (for going through the whole data). But since performance matters (particularly the searching part) I would like to chose the fastest and savest way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreData with sqlite store type is the way. You'd be able to fetch portions of data without reading the whole thing to the memory at once. This way you'd be able to generate custom `NSManagedObject` subclasses if you'd need custom behavior for each instance of an object.